# Need help getting started on this Complex Integral.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Here is the problem statement:

> Find $\displaystyle \oint_{_{C}} z^{3}\cos{\left(\frac{3}{z}\right)}dz$ for $C=|z|=1$

> recall that $\displaystyle \cos{(z)}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n)!}z^{2n}$

I'm not sure how to get started on this problem.  There is an issue with $z=0$ due to the cos function but I'm not sure how to implement the series form into the integral and then perform the integral.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT
Using the comment by @Conrad below.

For $\displaystyle \oint_{_{C}}z^{3}\cos{\left(\frac{3}{z}\right)}dz$

Let $\displaystyle w=\frac{1}{z}\Rightarrow -dw=\frac{1}{z^2}dz$

Then rewrite the integral using a factor of 1 written as $\displaystyle 1=\frac{z^2}{z^2}$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \oint_{_{C}}\frac{z^{3}z^{2}\cos{\left(\frac{3}{z}\right)}}{z^2}dz$,   next we swap out the $z$ and $dz$  and arrive at

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \oint_{_{C}}\frac{-\cos{(3w)}}{w^{5}}dw$, here we have a pole of order $5$ at $w=0$ and use the Residue Theorem to finish out.

Result using the residue theorem as stated below
$\displaystyle  \oint_{_{C}}\frac{-\cos{(3w)}}{w^{5}}dw = 2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim\limits_{w\to z_{0}}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}(w-z_{0})^{n} \frac{-\cos{(3w)}}{w^{5}} \right]$

plugging in $n=5$ and $z_{0}=0$

$\displaystyle  \oint_{_{C}}\frac{-\cos{(3w)}}{w^{5}}dw =  2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{(5-1)!}\lim\limits_{w \to 0}\frac{d^{5-1}}{dw^{5-1}}\left((w-0)^{5}\frac{-\cos{(3w)}}{w^{5}}\right) \right]$

$\displaystyle  \oint_{_{C}}\frac{-\cos{3(w)}}{w^{5}}dw =  2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{24}\lim\limits_{w \to 0}\frac{d^{4}}{dw^{4}}\left(-\cos{(3w)}\right) \right]$

$\displaystyle  \oint_{_{C}}\frac{-\cos{(3w)}}{w^{5}}dw =  2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{24}\lim\limits_{w \to 0}\left(-81\cos{(3w)}\right) \right]$

$\displaystyle  \oint_{_{C}}\frac{-\cos{(3w)}}{w^{5}}dw =  2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{24}\cdot(-81) \right]$

$\displaystyle  \oint_{_{C}}\frac{-\cos{(3w)}}{w^{5}}dw =  -\frac{27\pi i}{4}$ or $\displaystyle \frac{27\pi}{4i}$

I am trying to figure out why my answer is off by a factor of -1 to make it align with the correct answer @bob provided below.

Comment: $\int_C z^{k}dz=0$ except for $k=-1$. Interchange the sum and the integral.

Comment: @geetha290krm can you type out the integral that it creates?  I understand why the integral of $z^k$ is zero except for k=-1, because that function is analytic and the integral of it is just zero. Are you saying that by subbing in the series as an integral we end up with just some integral of $z^k$ with coefficients and its just =0 ?

Comment: Only one term ($n=2)$ will remain. Other terms are $0$.

Comment: equivalently to the above change variables $w=1/z$ and you get a standard Cuchy integral which can be solved either by the Cauchy formula for derivatives or by power series (note that $dz=-dw/w^2$ but the orientation of the unit circle changes too so the $-$ cancels out)

Comment: can one of yall(or both) write this out in a response so I can see it?

Comment: You've been given three hints so far, one of which is in the problem statement itself.  I'm confident that if you just start writing things out for yourself, the pieces will fall into place.  Just give it a try; edit your post to add your work, and if there are errors or places where you're unsure or confused, that's where you will get additional guidance.  We think that's the most effective way to learn.

Comment: My remark was not intended to be rude.  However, showing some of your own effort here is considered polite, especially after other people have so kindly taken time out of their day to give you what are rather good hints.  If that isn't enough, it is unreasonable to **expect** other people to give you the answer and call them out if they aren't meeting **your** needs, when all of this information is given to you **freely**.

Comment: @Conrad i think i figured it out with your suggestion.  I'm going to post it shortly when I finish typing it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the Laurent series,
$$f(z)=z^3\cos\left(\frac{3}{z}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-9)^n}{(2n)!}z^{3-2n}$$
as $z\to0$, so by [Cauchy's residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem),
$$\oint_{|z|=1}f(z)\ dz=2\pi i\text{Res}(f,0)=2\pi i\cdot\frac{81}{4!}=\frac{27\pi i}{4}.$$

Comment: figured out the intermediate steps with the help from some other peeps.  your answer is correct.  thank you

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:  I made mistakes in this one and just updated the original post

Using the comment by @Conrad above.

For $\displaystyle \oint_{_{C}}z^{3}\cos{\left(\frac{3}{z}\right)}dz$

Let $\displaystyle w=\frac{1}{z}\Rightarrow -dw=\frac{1}{z^2}dz$

Then rewrite the integral using a factor of 1 written as $\displaystyle 1=\frac{z^2}{z^2}$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \oint_{_{C}}\frac{z^{3}z^{2}\cos{\left(\frac{3}{z}\right)}}{z^2}dz$,   next we swap out the $z$ and $dz$  and arrive at

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \oint_{_{C}}\frac{-\cos{(w)}}{w^{5}}dw$, here we have a pole of order $5$ at $w=0$ and use the Residue Theorem to finish out.

Result using the residue theorem as stated below
$\displaystyle  \oint_{_{C}}\frac{-\cos{(w)}}{w^{5}}dw = 2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim\limits_{w\to z_{0}}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}(w-z_{0})^{n} \frac{-\cos{(w)}}{w^{5}} \right]$

plugging in $n=5$ and $z_{0}=0$

$\displaystyle  \oint_{_{C}}\frac{-\cos{(w)}}{w^{5}}dw =  2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{(5-1)!}\lim\limits_{w \to 0}\frac{d^{5-1}}{dw^{5-1}}\left((w-0)^{5}\frac{-\cos{(w)}}{w^{5}}\right) \right]$

$\displaystyle  \oint_{_{C}}\frac{-\cos{(w)}}{w^{5}}dw =  2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{24}\lim\limits_{w \to 0}\frac{d^{4}}{dw^{4}}\left(-\cos{(w)}\right) \right]$

$\displaystyle  \oint_{_{C}}\frac{-\cos{(w)}}{w^{5}}dw =  2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{24}\lim\limits_{w \to 0}\left(-\cos{(w)}\right) \right]$

$\displaystyle  \oint_{_{C}}\frac{-\cos{(w)}}{w^{5}}dw =  2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{24}\cdot(-1) \right]$

$\displaystyle  \oint_{_{C}}\frac{-\cos{(w)}}{w^{5}}dw =  -\frac{\pi i}{12}$ or $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{12i}$

Comment: It seems like you forgot the coefficient $3$ inside $\cos(\frac{3}{z})$ when making the substitution $w=\frac{1}{z}$, resulting in a result different than that of the other answer

Comment: Your'e absolutely right.  Let me rework it and see if i can get the same result as bob.  thank you for point that out @Fotis .  I was so focused on the sub i forgot the coefficient.

Comment: the integral is of $\oint_{_{C}}\frac{\cos{(3w)}}{w^{5}}dw$ not minus that since the change of varaible changes orientation so you get a $--$ like when you do $x=-t$ in real variables and you get $dx=-dt$ but the bounds invert too so you get another minus to put them increasingly - same phenomenon since on the reals the positive orientation is increasing while in the plane it is counterclockwise

Comment: @EvanHowington. Note that for the residue at $z=0$, you just need the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion of $f$ in my answer.